# Do you know any of C/C++ parsers which are capable of name and overload resolution?

Tags: c++, c, parsing, naming

I need a C/C++ language (not GCC but Microsoft Visual C++) parser able performing naming and overloading resolution and macro expansion. Nowadays I use Understand, but it is too buggy and doesn't provide all the features I need.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? There are many C/C++ parsers, but why isn't GCC good enough?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a Visual Studio plugin to staticly analyze your code in a GUI and not a generic C/C++ parsing library like [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). Correct? Also, is this the [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/) thingy that you mentionned?

Comment: [Gazelle](http://www.reverberate.org/gazelle/) is a relatively new parser system.

Comment: @GMan:  Can it actually be used to parse C++ though?  (From the top of the linked page, it says it is "for parsing context-free grammars;" the C++ grammar is decidedly not context-free.)

Comment: @James: Hm, I'm pretty sure that information about Gazelle is wrong. I was linked to a different page from Gazelle earlier today that said is has mechanisms for parsing context-sensitive grammars as well, and even plans to add scripting to make generic disambiguation callbacks.

Comment: Re Gazelle: Having a parser generator is a far cry from have a tested, robust parser for a language, let alone C++, or the more difficult issues of name and type resolution for C++.

Comment: Clang apparantly does not handle MS C++ completely: http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html

Comment: gcc preprocessor differs from MS C++ preprocessor. So clang and gcc are completely unuseful ^(

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a single parser to do both C and C++.  They are different langauges with different syntax and semantics.   You can get individual parsers for each.

See our [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) and [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html).  Both of these handle a variety of dialects (both GCC and MS), build ASTs, construct full symbol tables.  There is a preprocessor module that will perform either full expansion, or under your control, expand only certain conditionals and macros.

The C front end also has control flow, data flows, points-to and call graph construction.  Unlike Understand, which doesn't really have deep flow analysis, the C Front end will get the targets of indirect function calls correct (within conservative assumptions).

The C++ front end handles the full C++0X language.  We are in the process of completing control flow graph construction for it.

The underlying engine [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) provides customizable access to all this information.   It does not provide pretty pictures like Understand; it is intended to let you build custom analysis and program transformation tools.